# How to compare 2 inherited classes in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, next.js

Consider we have 2 classes `Animal` and `Dog`. Here `Dog` class is inherited from `Animal` class.

I need to check the type of this objects

how can I  achieve this

```js
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

//This obj can have both classes
const mixedObj: Animal | Dog = new Dog();

//---> here When i compare mixedObj with Animal class i need to get `false` but `true` is returned
console.log(mixedObj instanceof Animal);// returns: `true` 

console.log(mixedObj instanceof Dog);// returns: true
```

has any other ways to solve this problem...?

Comment: TypeScript type annotations are not available at runtime. `instanceof` checks the prototype chain of the _acutal_ type of `mixedObj`. The object is a Dog, and Dog extends Animal, so the instanceof check returns true.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `mixedObj.constructor === Animal`?

Comment: Yeah exactly, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, you're is asking about the *runtime* value of `mixedObj`, which is a JavaScript thing rather than a TypeScript thing.

`instanceof Animal` will be `true` for any object that has `Animal.prototype` anywhere in its prototype chain (typically because it was created by the `Animal` constructor, directly or indirectly [for instance, via `Dog`]). If you want to see if `mixedObj` contains a `Dog`, *specifically*, and not an `Animal`, you need to look at the `constructor` property:

```js
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

//This obj can have either class
const mixedObj/*: Animal | Dog*/ = new Dog();

console.log(mixedObj.constructor === Animal);// returns: `false` 

console.log(mixedObj.constructor === Dog);// returns: `true`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeBfAsAKFEhgBEB7Ac2gFMAPAFyvgBMYEU1Nc98B6HgFQAWiGKQBGAK2jAw8aILAA3KtUR1BVAE7TwUfMFLwIdaMkQ0qTAPKSAXHCSp0AH2hlKAXmjwqAdzcUABQAlADc+PqGEKQgVAB0IEFmFtaScQZGdJoArsB0pNoeRQ7sIGF80JpUdNmaRvYABgBmaBBUDdARBFEx8YnkgcmWNhLpUVm5+YXF7uU8ldW19dANE+1AA)

**But**, that's generally an antipattern. A better way, particularly since it'll work with TypeScript at compile-time, is to give `Dog` some feature that `Animal` doesn't have and test for that feature:

```js
class Animal {
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    bark() {
        console.log("Woof!");
    }
}

//This obj can have either class
const mixedObj/*: Animal | Dog*/ = new Dog();

console.log("bark" in mixedObj); // returns: `true` (would be `false` for an `Animal`)

if ("bark" in mixedObj) {
    mixedObj.bark(); // No error, because TypeScript knows that it's a `Dog`
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeBYAUAX111EhgBEB7Ac2gFMAPAFxvgBMYEU1NdpfoAjMACcA1gAoAlNxx9Z0YOXgRyIGgDoQVMQCIA6uXIAzAITaJAbh58C+QjgD09gCoALRDHL8AVvLDxoLmAAbjS0iAwuNELy4FBEihAM0MiIdDQsAPLeAFxwSKjoAD7QFNQAvNDwNADuJVoWdgpKKuqalDqCotrQiP4paZneFtCO0EI0DACuQkq5AAYMQpM0c9Bi1eSTICwCoXOGaBAr0Ibk0X7QcxwFcxJ2iIZr2p0i3b3JqelZXlLYMnz9L7eNQvSTmEb2aAAOXItCEQjOABpdsAwJMjtAnABPAAONAAysAhIgcUkRPByNUYBEwElwgByGBgS6lOa4PBAA)